# Updating the nested array element value in Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm new to MERN, I have created a system for the teachers to check the assignment.
My Schema looks like this

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const xyzSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'user_collections'
    },
    assignments:[{
        title_assignment:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        description_assignment:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        created_at:{
            type:Date,
            required:true,
            default:Date.now()
        },
        files:[],
        submitted:[{
            user:{
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref:'user_collections'
            },
            files:[],
            created_at:{
                type:Date,
                required:true,
                default:Date.now()
            },
            checked:{
                type:Boolean,
                default:false
            }
        }],
        due_dt:{
            type:Date,
            required:true
        }
    }],
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('abc',xyzSchema)
```

On Click of **checked** on frontend, I wan't to update the value of "checked" to true from "false".

My Route looks like this

```js
router.put('/assignments/check',
auth,
async(req,res)=>{
   
    try {
        let check = await Classroom.findOne(
            {"assignments._id":req.body.assignment_id,"assignments.submitted.user":req.body.user_id},
            {$set:{"assignments.$.submitted.$.checked":"true"}}} 
        )
        res.json(check)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
})
```

This code is not working for me. Can someone please suggest me something?
What I want to do is
1) Find the Aassignment using ID and submitted assignment array using the User ID inside it
2) Change the "checked" value for that user to "true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$[]` identifier. With arrayFilters in `update`.

[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up.*S*[%3Cidentifier%3E]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])

You also need to convert your Ids to Mongodb object Ids with `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` if the Ids are ObjectIds, otherwise it could be that the query works without errors but the fields wont get updated.

```
let check = await Classroom.update(
            {},
            { $set: {"assignments.$[assign].submitted.$[submitt].checked": "true" }},
            {
             arrayFilters: [
                  {
                     "assign._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.assignment_id)
                  },
                  {
                     "submitt.user": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id)
                  }
               ]
            }
```

The `$` identifier works only for 1 level of depth, if its more then you need to use `arrayFilters`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It did update the value from false true for that user but it deleted all other records in that submitted array.

Comment: @AkshayKankal strange, what got exactly deleted?

Comment: I had 2 records in submittd array. When I updated the records for 1 user, the other record got deleted.
Also the the first record got updated succesfully.

Comment: @AkshayKankal check for typos, i cant help you either without seeing the full code

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just added  {"assignments._id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.assignment_id)} in the first part and it worked perfect for me.
You saved me.